# Isomorphism between $L$-structures

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I have a question in particular on b), since this should simply be wrong, and only true for $n=m$. Also I have a concern on d).
Please have a look. I know it is a lot of text... Thank you!

> Let $L$ be the language $\{c\}$ where $c$ is constant symbol. Let $L^<=\{c,<\}$, $L^+=\{c,+\}$, $L^{<,+}=\{c,<,+\}$, where $+$ is a 2-digit function symbol and $<$ is a 2-digit relation symbol.
>
> We observe the structure $S_n$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ as universe (basis set) and $c$ gets interpreted as $n$.
>
> A $S_n$ structure can be expanded to a $L^{+,<}$-structure $S_n^{<,+}$, where $+,<$ have the usual interpretation. Similar $S_n^<$ and $S_n^+$.
>
> Show:
>
> a) $S_n\cong S_m$ for every $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$
>
> b) For every $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ exists exactly one isomorphism between $S_n^<$ and $S_m^<$.
>
> c) $S_n^{<,+}\cong S_m^{<,+}\iff n=m$
>
> d) When does $S_n^+\cong S_m^+$ hold?

a) is simple. We define $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}, f(x)=\begin{cases} m,\text{if x=n}\\ n,\text{if x=m}\\ x,\text{else}\end{cases}$

Obviously $f$ is a bijection and it holds $f(c^{S_n})=f(n)=m=c^{S_m}$. So $S_n\cong S_m$.

But b) should only hold for $n=m$, because we have to define the isomorphism as in a). Else we do not map constant symbols onto constant symbols.

And then $n<m\Leftrightarrow f(n)<f(m)\Leftrightarrow m<n$ which is a contradiction.

You can only make sense out of this when $n=m$, or am I missing something?

For c): $\Leftarrow$ is clear.

$\Rightarrow$. Let $S_n^{<,+}\cong S_m^{<,+}$ suppose $n\neq m$. Without loss of generality $n<m$. Then as in b) $n<m\Leftrightarrow m<n$ contradiction.

d):

This can not hold if $n\neq m$ and $n=0$ or $m=0$. Let $n=0$ (so $m\neq 0$).

Then $f(0)=f(0+0)\Leftrightarrow m=2m\Leftrightarrow m=0$ contradiction.

In particular this can not hold if $n\neq m$.

Let $n\cdot m:=\underbrace{m+\dotso +m}_{\text{n-times}}$ if $n>0$ and

$n\cdot m:=\underbrace{(-m)+\dotso (-m)}_{\text{n-times}}$ if $n<0$.

We have $f(n\cdot m)=f(m\cdot n)\Leftrightarrow n\cdot f(m)=m\cdot f(n)\Leftrightarrow n^2=m^2\Leftrightarrow n=m \vee n=-m$.

But $n\neq m$. So $n=-m$.

Then $f(n)=m=-n$. Choose $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $k\neq m,n$ and $n-k\neq m$. Then $f(n)=f((n+(-k))+k)=(n+(-k))+k=n$. So $n=-n$ but $n\neq 0$.

Is this correct? This seems overly 'complicated'.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

b) You are missing something. Instead of just swapping $n$ and $m,$ define the isomorphism as $x\mapsto x +(m-n).$ Will leave it to you to show this is order-preserving and the only possibility.

c) Similar error to (b). We know what the order isomorphism has to be from the uniqueness proved in (b) and it's pretty easy to see this doesn't preserve addition unless $m=n.$

d) Any addition-preserving map $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ is determined entirely by $f(1).$ What can $f(1)$ be in order that the map be a bijection?

Comment: I just gave an additional answer to c) and d). Do you mind looking over it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of spaceisdarkgreen, I want to give a full solution to the remaining c) and d).

c):

> We want to show that $S_n^{<,+}\cong S_m^{<,+}$ implies $n=m$.

So let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be an $L$-isomorphism.

Then $f$ has the properties:

> (I) $f(n)=m$
>
> (II) $a<b\Leftrightarrow f(a)<f(b)$
>
> (III) $f(a)+f(b)=f(a)+f(b)$

Suppose $n\neq m$. Without loss of generality we assume $n<m$.
If $n=0$ we have $f(0)=f(0+0)\stackrel{(III)}{=}f(0)+f(0)\Leftrightarrow 0=f(0)$

With (I) $m=0$. So $n\neq 0$.

Then we have $f(n)=\begin{cases} nf(1), n>0\\ nf(-1), n<0\end{cases}$

Where of course $nf(1)=\underbrace{f(1)+\dotso + f(1)}_{\text{n-times}}$

If $n>0$ then $m=f(n)=nf(1)$. So $n\mid m$ and $f(1)=\frac{m}{n}$.

It is $0<1<2\stackrel{(II)}{\Leftrightarrow} f(0)<f(1)<f(2)$

So $0<\frac{m}{n}<f(2)$. Now suppose that $f(1)>1$. Since $f$ is bijective there is some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $f(k)=1$.

Either $0<1<k$ or $k<0<1$.

In the first case we have $0<1<k\Leftrightarrow 0<\frac{m}{n}<1$. So $m<n$. Which is a contradiction.

If $k<0<1$ then $f(k)<f(0)$ but $f(k)=1<f(0)=0$ is also a contradcition.

The case $n<0$ is worked out analogously.

So indeed $n=m$.

d):

> When holds $S_n^+\cong S_m^+$

The isomorphism obvioulsy holds for $m\in\{\pm n\}$ and there are no other cases.

Like above we have $f(0)=0$ so $n\neq 0$, and $f(1)=\frac{m}{n}$. So $n\mid m$ and $n<m$.

Now we show that $m|n$:

Since $f$ is a bijection there is some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $f(k)=1$.

Then $mf(k)=m\Leftrightarrow f(mk)=m\Leftrightarrow mk=n$. So $m\mid n$.

Now we have $m\mid n$ and $n\mid m$. This only holds if $\pm m=n$.

Comment: No, property III should be $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b),$ not $a+b=f(a)+f(b).$ Both answers use the incorrect version in an essential way, so are wrong.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I hope everything is correct now...

Comment: (d) looks right, although I’m not sure why you say “the isomorphism obviously holds for...” What isomorphism? If $m=n$ identity is the isomorphism and if $m=-n$ then multiplying by $-1$ is the isomorphism. (c) I can’t really make sense of and it seems over complicated at the very least. Notice that in (d) you determined all the possible isomorphisms when there’s just addition... if we add the order relation then multiplying by negative one is no longer an isomorphism but identity still is. (And if you won’t do (d) before (c) in my answer I recommended you start with the answer to (b) instead.)

Comment: With "the isomorphism obviously holds for..." I meant that one immediatly sees the isomorphisms that you mentioned. What do you mean by you can not make sense out of c)? I do not think that it is overly complicated. There is no real big thought process involved. It could be done quicker, but is it incorrect? I do not see a mistake.

Comment: On closer inspection, it is probably correct but I still find it very difficult to read. Part of the problem is probably that you felt compelled to juggle the parameters $m,n$ of the problem when you don't need to:  instead of proving $m=n,$ prove that the only automorphism of $(\mathbb Z,<,+)$ is the identity, from which that fact follows. That's one layer of case analysis gone. Then the case analysis on $k$ can be replaced with "since $0$ is the immediate successor of $1$ in the ordering, $f(0)$ is the immediate successor of $f(1),$ and since $f(0)=0$ this means $f(1)=1$."

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for taking a closer look. And sorry for the caused difficulties. :)